# ClassNotFoundException: DirectoryService with apacheds-all already included

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-boot, ldap

I am implemented LDAP authentication in my Spring Boot Application. The dependencies added are as follows:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.directory.server</groupId>
        <artifactId>apacheds-all</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

However I am still getting following ClassNotFoundException:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'springSecurityFilterChain'
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [javax.servlet.Filter]
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/directory/server/core/DirectoryService
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.directory.server.core.DirectoryService
```

My maven dependency tree clearly shows apacheds-all is added successfully. 
[image]

Why am I still getting this error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Spring Security doesn't support Apache DS 2.0. Instead, you need to use 1.5.5. Also, note that later 1.5.x versions are not supported due to breaking API changes.

Comment: I can't seem to use `apache-all 1.5.5`, says `The requested version 1.6 by your slf4j binding is not compatible with [1.5.5, 1.5.6]`. However it works if I use `apacheds-server-jndi 1.5.5` instead.